# XPath expression returning empty list in scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I was scraping http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/records/index.html?id=2;type=team

What I do need is the link attached to the XPath expression

```
/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/ul[2]/li/a[2]
```

In the page it is the element marked by `"One-day Internationals"` under the list of match results by year. The above expression was obtained using the Firefox extension Firebug.

However it is returning an empty list. Have tried using alternate xpath expressions like

```
//div[@id="ciHomeContentlhs"]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/ul/li/a[2]/@href
```

with the same result.

the Xpath expression

```
//div[@id="ciHomeContentlhs"]/table
```

is giving me the table. However

```
//div[@id="ciHomeContentlhs"]/table/tbody
```

is returning an empty list. I've tested the xpath expressions out on
http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi and it shows the required `href` or node as the output. I can't seem to be able to get to work in `Python`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<tbody>` element is not a part of initial `HTML` source- it is generated by browser parser, so you shouldn't use it in your `XPath` expression.

You can use link text to match exact element:

```
//a[text()="One-Day Internationals"]
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks. I figured out a workaround, but had no idea why i was unable to.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove all `<tbody>` in your Xpath expression as Andersson is saying. The following expression is giving me a list (as u want) of only this element:

```
response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[4]/table/tr/td[1]/div[2]/table[1]/tr/td/ul[2]/li/a[2]/text()').extract()
```

Comment: This works too. Thanks.